# Does the graduate admission committee automatically consider you for a Master's program if they don't accept you for their Ph.D program?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, mathematics

I am applying for Math Ph.D programs, some of the schools say in their websites that they'll consider one for their MS program if one is not accepted to their PhD program.

I was wondering if all schools are like that, or it depends?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Consideration for MS if PhD rejected](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31869/consideration-for-ms-if-phd-rejected)

Comment: **Every department is different.**

Comment: Some departments might have no master's program at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some do, others don't. I have heard the term 'cash cows' many times when it comes master's student in graduate schools (Because PhD is almost always full funded in a way or another). Some schools might offer you an unfunded master's admission if you don't get into their PhD program, and many applicants think of this as a polite rejection.